# Python: for loops: using an index from a list and another index from another list

Tags: python, list, loops

I would like to loop as something like:

```
for j in range(1,4) and for k in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
               print(str(j) + ' is written ' + k)
```

I tried with `and` but it didn't work. How does someone get this effect?

And what would happen in the case that the two lists have different lengths? How could I still iterate through both of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `zip`

```
for j, k in zip(range(1,4), ['one', 'two', 'three']):
    print('{} is written {}'.format(j, k))    

1 is written one
2 is written two
3 is written three
```

If one is longer than the other, you could consider using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 7):

Check this out:

```
for j,k in enumerate(['one', 'two', 'three'], 1):
    print("{} is written {}".format(j, k))
```

Answer (score 4):

You should [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) 'em all!

```
for j, k in zip(range(1,4), ("one", "two", "three")):
    # use j and k
```

Comment: I choose you zipachu!

Comment: Why _two downvotes_?? You don't  like Pokémon? Or the `zip` function?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think there might be debate between which answer might be *better* between zip and enumerate.